# Conditional URL redirection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, url, redirect

I'm running a shiny app with an original URL "https://shinyapps.io/myapp", and a custom URL "http://mydomain/myapp".
I want to redirect all http connections to the original https URL since otherwise users won't be able to use geolocation in the app but I'm a real newbie in JavaScript and I cannot get it done.

I'm trying to test the URL using JavaScript code in the  of my app, but URL is redirected in all cases as if my condition was always true :

```
var protocol = location.protocol;
if (protocol == "http") {
  window.location.assign("https://shinyapps.io/myapp")
}
```

What is wrong with this ?
I had answers suggesting correcting protocol = "http" to protocol == "http", which I did, but my test is now always false instead of always true...
I guess problem comes from how to write "http" on the right side of the equality, I tried "http:", and "http://" but it didn't change anything.
Any clue ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: `=` is used for assignment, use `==` or `===` for comparing

Comment: You should be comparing strings in JavaScript using `==` or `===`, but _not_ plain `=`, which is just the assignment operator.  Most likely, your `if` condition is always returning true because the assignment is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `=` for comparison.

Use `==`or `===` instead.

Here your condition `protocol = "http"`is actually and assigment and is always true.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but protocol == "http" now returns always false, because of the way I write "http" I guess, I tried "http:", "http://" but it is still always false.

Comment: what is the value of `location.protocol` ?

Comment: console.log(location.protocol)
http: 
undefined

Comment: So the condition (location.protocol == "http:") should be true as far as i've  understood correctly the problem

Comment: My problem is : condition (location.protocol == "http:") is always false, or is not tested, as redirection never happens...

Comment: Edit : redirection never happens because Shinyapps with custom URL are displayed inside an iframe which prevents scripts from running...